# BIGINT conversion exercise Sybase ASE 15 7

Tags: sybase, bigint

Currently we are in process of converting production db tables from INT to BIGINT with Sybase ALTER command.
One of the table has 1.5Billion rows which we are unable to convert in one weekend time frame (ran for almost 43 hours then we killed it & restored the DB dumps).

Any other suggestion to convert this table quickly to BIGINT. This table has clustered, unique and non-clustered indexes on it.

I am thinking below solutions: Can you suggest the best way to do this?

1. Create a new column & update it with old value then drop the old column followed by renaming the new column.
2. BCP out the data, truncate the table, alter the table structure with new data types then BCP in the data
3. Partition the table into small tables then alter the table & merge it again.

Comment: My choice would be: BCP out the data, truncate the table, alter the table structure with new data types then BCP in the data, load should be considerbly faster then some update on 1,5billion rows, and all you need to do is alter the structure of the table.

Comment: Can someone confirm that load is faster in ASE than update, i was thinking about IQ and now i saw he is using ASE, the DML in ASE is pretty fast compared to IQ so maybe i was wrong?

Comment: Thanks, but I have indexes (1 cluster & 3 non-cluster) on that table, so we need to rebuild the indexes if I go for BCP - that takes huge time again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help but you could consider it.
If you can bcp out and sort the data, bcp'ing back into the new table, then you can create the clustered index WITH SORTED_DATA.  That saves a lot of time on a clustered index.  Sorting can be quicker using unix sort (and you can bcp to a pipe and sort from that straight back to a bcp-in from a pipe.)

If you have a db Server with several engines you can then recreate the non-clustered indexes concurrently.  That would save time (you'd hope it'd be about a third the time if the earlier recreate were in order.)

Otherwise maybe partitioning - you can bcp simultaneously to different partitions and index on different partitions (but we've not done this so, sorry, I haven't got useful advice for this.)

Answer (score 0):

Change with a short time window.

Create the new table without indexes and triggers.
   Load data from the "source table" to "target table".
   Create indexes with a postfix.

In a time window:
     Insert and update records that have changed since the initial load.
     Rename the "source table" a "backup source table".
     Rename the new table to the name of the source table.
     Create triggers in the new table.
     "Renaming indexes" of the new table.
     Validate that the two tables have the same information.
     Ready.